# How to cout the value for many times in recursion?

Tags: c++

i'm writing a program in C++ to print first 50 natural numbers using recursion, but i dont know how to print many values

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

  int printingNum(int n)
  {
      if(n==1) return 1;
      if(n <= 50)
        return printingNum(n-1);
  }
  int main()
  {
      int n;
      cin>>n;
      cout<<printingNum(n);
  }
```

I expect the output of this program is 1 2 3 .. 50, but the actual output is just 49.

Comment: you call `cout` *once* and expect *50* output?

Comment: `printingNum()` does not print anything.    The `main()` function prints the returned value.    It doesn't somehow print the value returned by every recursive call.

Comment: And, BTW, your claim that it prints the value `49` is false.   As shown, the code will print the value `1`.   Accordingly, voting to close the question as unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
void printingNum(int n)
{
    if(n==0) return;
    printingNum(n-1);
    cout << n;
}
```